# Using PDO prepared statements MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create an OOP style CRUD class in PHP and using PDO prepared statements to protect against injections. My connection is working and I can perform regular SQL queries from the class but when I try to incorporate PDO's prepare function, I get an error that I either have a MySQL syntax error or PDO prepare is undefined.

The error gets thrown at `$p_query = $db->prepare($sql)` line. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

class Crud {
    protected $db;

    private static function fetchQuery($sql, $values) {
        echo $sql;
        var_dump($values);
        $db = Db_conn::pdoBuilder();
        $p_query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $p_query->execute($values);
        $results = $p_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $results;    
    }
    public static function show($tbl, $id) {
        $sql = '"SELECT * FROM (:tbl) WHERE id = (:id)"';
        $values = [':tbl' => $tbl, ':id' => $id];
        $results = self::fetchQuery($sql, $values);
        return $results;

    }

    public static function listAll($tbl) {
        $sql = '"SELECT * FROM (:tbl)"';
        $values = [':tbl' => $tbl];
        $results = self::fetchQuery($sql, $values);
        return $results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the output of `$sql` and `$values`

Comment: did you try removing double quotation marks from the query? What about removing the parenthesis from table name and column filters?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu sql: "SELECT * FROM (:tbl)" values: array(1) { [":tbl"]=> string(6) "client" }

Comment: Table names can't be parametrized. A prepared statement basically is a partial query, where all that is missing is the data that goes in the where clause or `VALUES` (in case of an insert)\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off:

```
$sql = '"SELECT * FROM ?"';
```

Why are you quoting your query? It should be:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ?';
```

Next:

```
$values = [':tbl' => $tbl];
```

Where is the placeholder `:tbl` in your query? You're using `?`, change the `$sql` string to:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM :tbl';
```

Which immediately poses another problem: the table you're using in your prepared statement can't be bound after you create the prepared statement. Impossiburu. Never going to happen. The best you can do is something like:

```
$sql = sprintf(
    'SELECT * FROM `%s`',
    //remove illegal chars
    str_replace([' ', '\\', '`', '"', "'"], '', trim($tbl))
);
```

Lastly, applied to this bit:

```
$sql = '"SELECT * FROM (:tbl) WHERE id = (:id)"';
$values = [':tbl' => $tbl, ':id' => $id];
$results = self::fetchQuery($sql, $values);
```

This means you'll have to write:

```
$sql = sprintf(
    'SELECT * FROM `%s` WHERE id = :id',
    $tbl
);
$values = [':id' => $id];
return self::fetchQuery($sql, $values);
```

But really, you're not using prepared statements as well as perhaps you could. The best thing about prepared statements is that they're *reusable*. Wrapping `PDO` to get a cleaner API hasn't been done as far as I know. Most attempts turn out to actually lessen the power of the extension, or build a bloated abstraction layer around it. That needn't be a bad thing, provided you're building a full-blown ORM/DBAL. [I've been quite vocal about this stuff here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29362/class-for-reducing-development-time/29394#29394), you might want to read through it